# How can I count the keys in list of dictionaries? | python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count, each

For example there is a list:

```
list = [{'brand': 'Ford', 'Model': 'Mustang', 'year': 1964}, {'brand': 'Nissan', 'model': 'Skyline', 'year': 1969} ...]
```

I want to count there are how many model from each. How can I do it?

By the way sorry for the bad formatting I am new here yet.

I tried this method:

```
model_count = {}

for i in list:
if i['Model'] in model_count:
  model_count[i] += 1
else:
  model_count[i] = 1
```

And I got this error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: [See here for how to format code in your questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: I think you mean `model_count[i['Model']] += 1` etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the key "Model" appears in every dictionary capitalized like this, you can use the code below

```python
my_list = [{'brand': 'Ford', 'Model': 'Mustang', 'year': 1964}, {'brand': 'Nissan', 'Model': 'Skyline', 'year': 1969}]

models = {}
for dictionary in my_list:
    model = dictionary.get('Model', None)
    if model is not None:
        models[model] = models.get(model, 0) + 1

print(models)
```

Output:

```
{'Mustang': 1, 'Skyline': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
models = Counter(i['Model'] for i in mylist)
```